Installation using spack : cmake cannot find python3
I am trying to install a package on an HPC machine using spack. While building one of the dependencies (this) the following error is encountered.
CMake Error at /netfs/$USER/spack/opt/spack/linux-rhel7-skylake_avx512/gcc-11.2.0/cmake-3.27.9-6ut2kk3mda2gacsaaikhkonwioq35ecg /share/cmake-3.27/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
     91      Could NOT find Python3 (missing: Python3_EXECUTABLE Interpreter) (Required
     92      is at least version "3.9")
     93    
     94          Reason given by package:
     95              Interpreter: Wrong version for the interpreter "/bin/python"

A relevant python module (python3.10) was loaded beforehand. The package is added in packages.yaml as well.
packages:
  python:
    externals:
    - spec: python@3.10.14+bz2+crypt+ctypes+dbm+lzma+nis+pyexpat+pythoncmd+readline+sqlite3+ssl+tix+tkinter+uuid+zlib
      prefix: /lustre/machine/local/apps/python3/3.10

How can I resolve this?

Python external is a tricky one, I recommend you to remove the external and let spack install its own python.
